# How to use .change() check on only part of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a bunch of html check boxes on a page, but want to have two different groups of checkboxes. I'm thinking that I can assign them into a class or insert them into a div, so that I can somehow refer to them separately...? Just unsure how to do this syntaxically.

For example, currently I'm using

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ /*insert my code functionality here*\ });
```

to refer to the checkboxes, but this changes all of my checkboxes, when I only want it to apply to half of them.

Comment: Easiest way is to assign each group a different class, without necessarily adding styles for that class.

Comment: Then you can use two `classes`.

Comment: It seems you have the answer.

Comment: Identify the groups by diferent classes, then you can determine it by the class via jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="group1" name="chk1" />Check One
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="group1" name="chk2" />Check Two

<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="group2" name="chk3" />Check One
<input type="checkbox" value="4" class="group2" name="chk4" />Check Two​
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type=checkbox].group1').change(function(){
   // code
});

$('input[type=checkbox].group2').change(function(){
   // code
});
```

[**An Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/56NZj/).

Comment: Welcome, glad to know that, it helped you in someway  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to separate them into two groups..

```
.tobechecked  // Assign a class to all the checkboxes that need to 
              // for this event

$('.tobechecked').change(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the groups by diferent classes, then you can determine it by the class via jquery.

```
$('.specific_group_class').change(function(){..}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your question, use classes.

Then you can do as such:

```
$(".check-1, .check-2").change(function(e) {
    /* do work */
});
```

## See jsFiddle

Comment: This is also really cool and definitely a different look on solving the problem. I didn't know you could pass in two arguments like that. Thanks for posting it! :)